# IOS DBAccess migration to new table structure

Tags: ios, database, migration, field, dbaccess

I'm reading DBAccess documentation to understand if it can fit my needs.

My question is about migration.

For example: I have an existing app, implemented with DBAccess, using a table "Person" with the following fields:
- id
- name
- surname
- address

What happens to database if I add other two fields to Person class:
- email
- phone_number
?
Does DBAccess automatically add new fields to database table?
Is there a way to specifiy default values for new added fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you add those two additional properties DBAccess will automatically add the additional columns.

At present, there is no ability to specify a default value for the new columns, they will all be initialised with NULL as you would expect.

Your suggestion about default values is interesting, i'm surprised that has not come up before.  It seems both easy to implement and quite a logical feature.  The only small weird thing would be that if I were to add the method

```
+ (id)defaultValueForProperty:(NSString*)propertyName;
```

to the framework, and then called that when creating a new column, would users perhaps expect this to happen per row and not once when creating a column, so they can customise that value, perhaps calculate it from contents elsewhere.

I would enjoy your feedback as to what you feel would be an appropriate solution.

I am personally leaning towards both a class and an instance method, and if the developer implements an instance method, then every individual row will be parsed and re-written which could be slow, but also a very useful feature.

Either way, it shouldn't take more than an hour or so for such a simple feature to be added.  We just need to see if we can see any pitfalls.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I think that a class method would be very usefull, in particular when adding new (o creating) fields that can not be null.

Comment: An instance method, as you say, can be very slow for large tables. Maybe it is better to provide a way to run some sql query as a fix for existing data, this can be faster. Or the possibility to implement a class function that is called every time the table is modified.

Comment: I take it, so I understand your reasoning behind this it is to make queries behave themselves.  Such as "WHERE surname == '' OR surname IS NULL".  Because, all the objects will have their default property values.  For instance, if you were to add a column age, although the column value in SQLite would be NULL, the value in the class would be 0.  When that object was persisted, it would then be saved with a 0 and not NULL.  I'm going to make the changes, because they are simple, but I wonder if there is another scenario I should be thinking of, that I have not yet considered.

Comment: We are currently implementing the upgrade mechanism, it's a brute of a problem to solve.  We do actually have a revision system in place, where the entity is called with a current revision and you get to execute some SQL against it, but it's breaks the rigid nature of DBAccess. I'll explain quickly that point.  We check the integrity of every property that is set and because there is no way to do anything that could break integrity directly with the DB (well you could, but not using the framework), we know that short of serious internal SQLite errors, the committals are guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: I understand your explanation and I agree with you on the integrity problem. I'm going to start using DBAccess in my next project, your answers helped me to take a decision, so... thank you for your support :)

Comment: Hi @Patrik, v1.06.1 has the change discussed above in it.  Slightly changed as we felt a dictionary was a cleaner implementation.  Here is a link to the documentation and example of it. Thanks, Adrian. http://www.db-access.org/default-property-values